# Chromedriver out of memory

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I recently changed from PhantomJS to Chromedriver. When running chromdriver in Docker, after a while, I get the pod evicted with 'The node was low on resource: nodefs.' and I see using 'kubectl describe nodes' 'OOMKilling' and 'Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 452 (chrome) score 1867 or sacrifice child' . So I think this is a memory leak/memory issue. I am running my driver with:

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--incognito')
    options.add_argument('--disable-application-cache')
```

Is there anything else that I need to set/do?

Comment: Have you tried without the no-sandbox flag?

Answer (score 1):

*Nothing is wrong with the **chromedriver***. Its the docker instance that ran out of memory.

### You need to move your docker instance on a system with more memory

. Other option is to optimize the OOM process killer and fine tune the processes. You can read more about the capacity tuning [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/s-memory-captun).

Comment: Hi. This never occurred when I used PhantomJS, so I think it still is an issue with chromedriver/chrome. Any thoughts regarding how to make sure chrome does not use as much resources?

Comment: you can add these options for further optimisation. options.add_arguments("test-type");
options.add_arguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");  
options.add_arguments("--enable-precise-memory-info"); 
options.add_arguments("--disable-default-apps");